# Angular2+ material customize datepicker date view

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular5

Is it possible to customize [angular2+ material datepicker's](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) date view like below?

[image]

The main libs and version:

```
angular: 5.2.9
@angular/material: 5.2.4
```

Comment: have you played with css?

Comment: @PardeepJain, I tried, but the problem is I can't add dynamic classes to the different type of date

Comment: Oh, probably then you can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I figure out how to resolve it finally.

Coz I'm using angular5, so one possible solution is like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-custom-cell), see below snippet:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tracker');
      let x =  elements[0].querySelectorAll('.mat-calendar-body-cell');
      x.forEach(y => {
        let c = new Date(y.getAttribute("aria-label"));
        if(c < this.startDate){
          const cellContent = y.querySelector('.mat-calendar-body-cell-content');
          cellContent.classList.add('custom-calendar-cell');
        }
      });
    });
```

For angular6+, you can refer to this [sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqokadeonrn?file=app%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts).